# Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed ,When tried to update image

Tags: laravel, file-upload, categories, banner

I tried to update my image for category banner using Laravel(v8).
This is my code to update any image, first thing I checked was whether there is any image. If there ware any, I removed them. Then I added the new image.

But it showed me this error, Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed ,When tried to update image.

Please help me to solve this.

Edit: My image was update without delete the old image.

```
if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()){
    
        $image = $request->file('image');
    
        $imageName= $image->getClientOriginalName().Str::random(5).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->storeAs('category_image', $imageName);
    
        $category = Category::find($id);
        if($category->banner !==null){
            unlink(public_path().'/allfiles/category_image/'.$category->banner);
        }
        $category->banner = $imageName;
        $category->save();
    
    }
    
        Category::find($id)->update([
    
            'name' => trim($request->category)
        ]);
```

Error messages,
[This is error detail's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KxvRv_0Gr-lmvf61JyBnmw4NRvH9xSnF/view?usp=sharing)

[This error showing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ESqL6QCs57_UxAnKxNzLgJKuY6UIB4NO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please upload the complete error trace or the image of the error trace?

Comment: Are you trying to return the uploaded image to User?

Comment: No, I just want to update image for category's banner.

Comment: I share the error image link , Please check it. Saud

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the actual problem, I removed old image link manually from the database and then tried to update a new image. Then it got updated successfully. Next, I updated the same image again to confirm whether it works or not, and it worked without any error. Maybe it was the problem with the browser session or the previous database image link.